# Index - Main entry without page number

Tags: indexing

As you can see in the picture, I am adding index entries to my thesis.
However, there are some main entries, like `probability` or `random`, are
not defined or discussed separately. Only the 
sub-entries `probability density function`,
`probability measure`, and `probability space` are defined.
The same are true for `random element` and `random variable`.
I think it is not good to have page numbers after the main entries,
which are not defined. Is there a way to remove page number for such entries?

[image: index]

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example of code?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should I still provide a ME now?

Comment: It's always better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just don't have to add `\index{probability}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{42}

a\index{probability!space}\index{probability!measure}

\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{44}

b\index{random!element}\index{random!value}

\clearpage

c\index{probability!density function}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]